# Delete lines from one file if they contain a regex of content in another file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a large file (150K+ lines) containing DNS records, I'll call that FileA.  I have a smaller file containing certain names, FileB.  I want to delete all lines in FileA that *end with* what's in FileB.  But I do **not** want to delete the line if the name appears at the beginning of the record.

I know how to use `grep -v name$` to manually remove the names that appear at the end of the record, but I need a loop to go through the whole FileB.  So far my attempts have failed.

Here's an example I hope illustrates what I'm after:

```
FileA:
hosta IN A 10.20.30.40
hostb IN A 20.30.40.50
myurl IN CNAME hostb
yours IN CNAME hostb
```

If FileB contains hostb, only the last two lines are deleted; the first two lines are left as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-f` flag to grep for all lines in FileB:

```
grep -v -f FileB FileA
```

This is almost what you want. But this removes also lines where the patterns from `FileB` are *not* at the end, and you explicitly stated that it should only match when it is at the end. So we need to modify `FileB` accordingly. We can use `sed`, to add the `regex` for the end of line, which is the `$` sign:

```
sed 's/$/$/' FileB
```

This looks like it's substituting nothing, but it is in fact adding a `$` at every end of line.

Now we can use process substitution to put all of this together:

```
grep -v -f <(sed 's/$/$/' FileB) FileA
```

Comment: Better also add a whitespace at the beginning of the line or a`bar` line in FileB will also remove a FileA line ending in `foobar`

Comment: Should add: it also completed instantly.

Answer (score 0):

To loop entire FileB you can use approach like:

```
for i in `cat FileB`
do
<do your work>
done
```

But maybe will be better to filter also by CNAME

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you can do it like this:

```
sed -n '/^[^ ]*$/{H;d;};G;/ \(.*\)\n.*\n\1/d;P' fileB fileA
```

This is: First process fileB. If the lines contain no spaces, they are supposed to be hostnames in fileB and we add them to the hold space and go on (`{H;d;}`)

All other lines are supposed to be of fileA. By appending the hold space with the host name list (`G`), all lines with the last word of the line that get repeated in host name list can be deleted. The remaining lines are printed without the trailing list (`P`). Option `-n` supresses default output.

**Edit:**
Actually one should do

```
sed -n '/^[^ ]*$/{H;d;};G;/ \(.*\)\n.*\n\1\n/d;/ \(.*\)\n.*\n\1$/d;P' fileB fileA
```

to avoid special cases.

Comment: Seems overly complex, but I did try it.  

After more than 30 minutes of pegging the CPU, it was still churning before I killed it.  
    

    `PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND`  
    
    `5593 piotr  20   0 1019m 961m  656 R 100.0 12.0  13:34.29 sed`

Comment: So I suppose that fileB is not that small? Execution time will grow linear with fileA, but Regular expressions with back references can slow down exponentially with length of fileB. Using `\([^ \n]*\)` instead of `\(.*\)` should drastically reduce execution time. If you are still interested, I can explain.

Comment: No, I did test run with FileB only 76 records.  
  
Thanks for the help anyway, some aspects of sed I've never played with.